# Meaning/Abbreviation of IAAD IA & IAADIADOO

Tags: test, test-results, procedure-purposes, nurse-practitioner

Did anyone ever come across any procedures/tests that starts with IAAD IA or IAADIADOO (Test for specific Pathogen). If yes, can you please tell me what does that IAAD IA or IAADIADOO mean or stands for? For example, IAAD IA GIARDIA, IAADIADOO Influenza tests, etc.

To keep it simple I am working to find some good procedures/medical tests for a patients to understand their patient journey for specific indications like UC & MS. I see a good amount of patients going through these tests that starts with IAAD IA/IAADIADOO along with the pathogen they are looking for. For example there is a CPT code associated for the test IAAD IA GIARDIA, which I believe is basically the test to diagnose giardiasis.

But I want to understand what exactly the IAAD IA stands for or the meaning behind it. There is no info in Google regarding this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please let us know what research you have done on this topic so far.

Comment: To keep it simple I am working to find some good procedures/medical tests for a patients to understand their patient journey for specific indications like UC & MS. I see a good amount of patients going through these tests that Starts with IAAD IA/ IAADIADOO along with the pathogen they are looking for. For example there is a CPT code associated for the test IAAD IA GIARDIA, which I believe is basically the test to diagnose giardiasis. But I want to understand what exactly the IAAD IA stands for or the meaning behind it. There is no info in Google regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These look like they are from CPT codes ("Current Procedural Terminology"; these are billing codes). They probably come with a numeric descriptor; you're looking for a "long descriptor" for that code.

IAAD is "infectious agent antigen detection"; IA is "immunoassay". DOO is "direct optical observation".

I found it by searching "IAADIADOO", which led me to a particular CPT code "87804", which led me to this PDF:

[Commonly Ordered COVID-19, Influenza, and RSV Clinical Diagnostic
Laboratory Tests for which Medicare Allows One Test Without a
Practitioner Order During the PHE*](https://www.cms.gov/files/document/covid-ifc-2-flu-rsv-codes.pdf)

which gave the long descriptor:

> Infectious agent antigen detection by immunoassay with direct optical observation; Influenza

You're probably better off starting with the actual codes, and looking for them directly, rather than trying to find them from the acronym. Contrary to "there is no info in Google", I found this in Google in just a couple minutes.

Comment: `Contrary to "there is no info in Google" I found this in Google in just a couple minutes.` -- In OP's defense, I did the same few minutes in google and even found the same PDF and CMS page, but I never made the connection with the acronyms because they're not spelled out anywhere I could find even though I went further looking for acronyms used in assays, billing, etc.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yeah, that's fair. The key to finding it is realizing these abbreviations are associated with numeric CPT codes, and then finding a source where the whole phrase is paired with the code rather than the abbreviation paired with the code. It's likely that OP's dataset contains the codes themselves, though, too, so if they start there they can skip a step.

Answer (score -1):

IAAD also stand for International Albinism awareness day, recognising both the challenges and achievements of those with the medical condition of albinism. On Nov 18th 2014 the UN General Assembly adopted a resolution establishing June 13th as International Albinism Awareness Day, confirming the global focus on albinism advocacy.